# SQL query with GROUP BY to show badges and points by user and course

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following database schema. My goal is to obtain a result set that lists the total badge points earned by each user. The badges might be earned in different courses. I want to include the courseid and the average score per course.

Users table:

```
| id | username |
|----|----------|
|  1 |    user1 |
|  2 |    user2 |
|  3 |    user3 |
```

Badges table:

```
| id | badgename | points | courseid |
|----|-----------|--------|----------|
|  1 |   badge a |     15 |        1 |
|  2 |   badge b |     10 |        1 |
|  3 |   badge c |     20 |        1 |
|  4 |   badge d |     15 |        2 |
|  5 |   badge e |     10 |        2 |
|  6 |   badge f |     25 |        2 |
```

BadgeAssignments table:

```
| userid | badgeid |
|--------|---------|
|      1 |       1 |
|      2 |       2 |
|      3 |       3 |
|      1 |       4 |
|      2 |       5 |
|      3 |       6 |
|      1 |       5 |
|      2 |       4 |
|      3 |       3 |
```

Courses table:

```
| courseid | coursename |
|----------|------------|
|        1 |   course 1 |
|        2 |   course 2 |
```

I have ended up with the following code, and I think it works fine:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(b.points), courseid, 
   (SELECT AVG(points) FROM Badges WHERE courseid = b.courseid) as courseAVG
FROM
  Badges b INNER JOIN BadgeAssignments ba ON b.id = ba.badgeid
  INNER JOIN Users u ON ba.userid = u.id
GROUP BY userid, b.courseid
```

which brings me this result:

```
| userid | SUM(b.points) | courseid | courseAVG |
|--------|---------------|----------|-----------|
|      1 |            15 |        1 |        15 |
|      1 |            25 |        2 |   16.6667 |
|      2 |            10 |        1 |        15 |
|      2 |            25 |        2 |   16.6667 |
|      3 |            40 |        1 |        15 |
|      3 |            25 |        2 |   16.6667 |
```

The numbers seem to be correct. I wonder if my query makes sense? and if it needs to be revised?

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2310c/2).

Comment: Please include your working code in the question

Comment: That's the best you can get on MySQL, you need to access `Badges` twice to get the individual and the average points. Two remarks: You should add an alias to `SUM(b.points)` and there's no Primary Key in the `BadgeAssignments` table, the same user can get the same batch more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly based on the current tables definition, I agree that it doesn't seem possible to have a better way of querying the needed results.

But it appears that performance might be improved using a slightly different approach, assuming that likely:

- the number of courses and badges is reduced, compared to the number of users
- courses and badges have relatively stable content (don't change daily!)

In the other hand we can notice that, in the current approach, `courseAVG` is computed again when the query is launched (more over, I'm not sure the optimizer takes care of computing it only once, rather than for each user/course pair!).

So an alternative approach might be:

- add a `pointsavg` field to the `Courses` table
- compute it in a separate `UPDATE` query (could be launched through a trigger applying `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE` on `Badges` and `Courses`

Here is it:

```
UPDATE Courses c
SET pointsavg = (
  SELECT AVG(points)
  FROM Badges b
  WHERE b.courseid = c.courseid
  GROUP BY courseid
);
```

Then we can simply use this `pointsavg` in the main query:

```
SELECT
  u.username,
  SUM(b.points) AS userCoursePoints,
  c.coursename,
  c.pointsavg AS courseAVG
FROM
  Users u,
  BadgeAssignments ba,
  Badges b,
  Courses c
WHERE ba.userid = u.id
  AND b.id = ba.badgeid
  AND c.courseid = b.courseid
GROUP BY u.username, b.courseid
```

Note that I took the opportunity to output `username` and `coursename` instead of their simple id, supposing it's closer to what is generally needed.

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11c60/1/0):